# segmentation fault while reading with read

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, system-calls

Why am I getting a segmentation fault here? I need to write a program in which, using system calls, I need to print lines in reverse order.

```
struct Stack {
    int top;
    char a[MAX];
};
    
int main() {
  struct Stack * st;
  st -> top = -1;

  char ch;
  int strings = 0;

  while (read(0, &ch, 1) > 0) {
    //push(st,ch);
    if (ch == '\n') // segmentation fault
      ++strings;
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure the segfault is actually happening there and not earlier, say, at `st -> top = -1;`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yes, I still had a problem, where you say. I fixed it. Thanks!